# Angular данные на странице не изменяются при изменениях в коде

Tags: angular2, angular4, angular

вот такая беда, не изменяется отображение страниц, вот код шапки сайта, когда я хочу изменить название ссылки, это изменение не происходит, отображается старое.

navbar.ts

```
import { Component, OnDestroy }   from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService }            from '../services/auth';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'navbar',
templateUrl: '../templates/navbar.html'
})

export class NavbarComponent implements OnDestroy {
public isLoggedIn: boolean = localStorage.getItem('token') ? true : 
false;
private _isLoggedInSubscription;

constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {
this._isLoggedInSubscription = _authService.isLoggedIn.subscribe((value) => {
  if (value == undefined) return; 
  this.isLoggedIn = value; 
  });
 }

logout() {
this._authService.logout();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
this._isLoggedInSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
}
```

navbar.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<ul *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="nav navbar-nav">
  <!-- Logged in -->
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a routerLink="/admin/tasks" class="nav-link">Tasks</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a (click)="logout();" href="javascript:void(false);" class="nav-link">Sign out</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <ul *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" class="nav navbar-nav">
  <!-- Logged out -->
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a routerLink="/login" class="nav-link">Sign in</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a routerLink="/registration" class="nav-link">Sign up</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

Вот ссылка на весь код, [GitHub](https://github.com/andrea2010/B)

Подскажите как мне изменить, что не так.

Comment: Кэш сбрасывали? Попробуйте в режиме "инкогнито".

Comment: Попробовал в режиме инкогнито, изменений нет.

Comment: А почему вы решили, что оно должно меняться?

Comment: Как бы это код этой страницы, мне нужно убрать одну ссылку из этой шапки, почему оно должно меняться, а разве отображение не должно меняться при изменении кода?